# Inherited classes don't appear in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 and Entity Framework.

I have 4 classes (`meat`, `dairy`, `breads` and `notdiaryOrMeat`) that all inherit from class `Food`.

In the SQL class all the dbsets for the inherited classes but only class `Food` appears in SQL Server.

Why can't I see the different classes in SQL Server?

Comment: Pleae provide a [mcve]

Comment: Because it's TPH inheritance.

Comment: @gertArnold what is TPH?

Comment: @NineBerry i have for example a class that inherts all the base class vars but i can see only the base class objects in sql server

Comment: It's [Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).

Comment: Are you using Entity (dbContext)?  If so there is a mapping between the c# classes and the database.  If you are only seeing some of the tables/columns in the database than the mapping may need to be refresh to update to match you current configuration.